# How to create an installer with InnoSetup running in only one computer to prevent unauthorized copy

Tags: c++, qt, inno-setup

I am using Innosetup to create an installer for my application (test.exe using Qt creator). I need that my application should be running on only one machine (unauthorized copies in other computer). I don't know how to make a function in Innosetup to identify if the address IP corresponds to the authorized machine or not. Else it should not run my application.

Comment: ip address isn't a great choice, the user can easily change their ip address to the required value, install your software then change it back

Comment: What prevents the user to copy over a working installation from an authorized machine?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have no problem with installing my software using Innosetup. My problem is how can I protect its from unauthorized copies and be running in only one computer. thanks

Comment: I need that my application should be running on only one computer. The user cannot copy .exe file and run it in another computer.

Comment: the objective is that the application should be running on only one computer. I should protect its from unauthorized copies. Several people use this application, it should be protected.  Thanks

Comment: You should check authorisation in application, not in installer

Comment: If you want real copy-protection, you may consider something like [WIBU CodeMeter](https://www.wibu.com/products/codemeter.html). As already said, you have to authorize the execution of the application. Restricting the setup doesn't buy much. Instead, it might be intentional that everybody can install your S/W (to feed the apes) but only authorized can run it.

Comment: You may also consider that a variety of companies (and even big ones) doesn't require any authorization for their products but provide even the source code for it. However... IMHO, this is not an option for niche products where the number of customers is very limited in general (not to mention that they probably know each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an solution for anti-copy the application, you can read the SID of the PC installed, store the SID in your application. Every time your application launches, the first step is to read the SID, then compare to the initial SID, if not match, exit your application.

Comment: Thanks you. It is very good idea. I which is not complex to do.